# (Python) Regex to extract network-object group from Cisco config

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a **network group from a Cisco config using Python and regular expressions**.
The group starts with `object-group network Cloudflare` and just after that, there are one or more subnets like  `network-object 173.245.48.0 255.255.240.0`.
The text would be

```
object-group network Cloudflare
 network-object 173.245.48.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 103.21.244.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 103.22.200.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 103.31.4.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 141.101.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 108.162.192.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 190.93.240.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 188.114.96.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 197.234.240.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 198.41.128.0 255.255.128.0
 network-object 162.158.0.0 255.254.0.0
 network-object 104.16.0.0 255.248.0.0
 network-object 104.24.0.0 255.252.0.0
 network-object 172.64.0.0 255.248.0.0
 network-object 131.0.72.0 255.255.252.0
```

While using this regex `(?P<name>object-group network Cloudflare)\n(?P<subnets> network-object \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\n)*`
I get 3 match groups, of which only the 1st is usable but it contains the header `object-group ...`.
Can it be improved?
https://regex101.com/r/s925cq/1

Comment: What's the official name for this file format? Chances are pretty good that there's a python module ready to parse it and give you all the information you need from it without the need for regexs at all.

Comment: Your regex looks to work perfectly. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please give some context and/or code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't think it has a name. It's the format used by Cisco ASA to define group of network objects. In this case the 'members' are subnets.

Comment: @PJProudhon What I'm trying to achieve is a script to automatically extract just the subnets contained in the 'Cloudflare' group.
If you open the regex101 url, you'll see that in the first match group, the first row is also extracted.
I just wanted to know if with a better expression I could extract only the rows starting with ` network-object `

Comment: https://github.com/topics/cisco-asa seems to list quite a few repos. Perhaps there's something useful in there.

Comment: @mlazzarotto91 See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3X4Urk/1) ?

Comment: You can get all the network objects in named group `subnets` with `(?P<name>object-group network Cloudflare)\n(?P<subnets>(?: network-object (?:\d+\.){3}\d+ (?:\d+\.){3}\d+\n)*)` See https://regex101.com/r/OloB8E/1

Answer (score 1):

```
data = """
 network-object 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
object-group network Cloudflare
 network-object 173.245.48.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 103.21.244.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 103.22.200.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 103.31.4.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 141.101.64.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 108.162.192.0 255.255.192.0
 network-object 190.93.240.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 188.114.96.0 255.255.240.0
 network-object 197.234.240.0 255.255.252.0
 network-object 198.41.128.0 255.255.128.0
 network-object 162.158.0.0 255.254.0.0
 network-object 104.16.0.0 255.248.0.0
 network-object 104.24.0.0 255.252.0.0
 network-object 172.64.0.0 255.248.0.0
 network-object 131.0.72.0 255.255.252.0
access-list outside
"""

regex=r"object-group network (?P<network>\S+)|network-object\s(?P<subnet>\S+?)\s(?P<mask>\S+)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, data)
result = []
network_group = {"network": "Unknown"}


for cnt, match in enumerate(matches):
    info = match.groupdict()
    info1 = {k: v for k, v in info.items() if v is not None}
    if check:=info.get("network"):
        network_group =   {"network": check} if check else network_group
    if not info.get("network"):
        result.append(network_group | info1)
result
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the network objects in named group *subnets* with:

```
(?P<name>object-group network Cloudflare)\n(?P<subnets>(?: network-object (?:\d+\.){3}\d+ (?:\d+\.){3}\d+\n)+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?P<name>object-group network Cloudflare)` Named group *name*, match literally
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?P<subnets>` Named group *subnets*

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

    - `network-object`
    - `(?:\d+\.){3}\d+ (?:\d+\.){3}\d+\n` match 2 times the digits with dot part followed by a newline
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times (to match at least 1 line)
- `)` Close group *subnets*

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pCRDig/1).